# Convolution of a probability measure with a smooth function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, convolution

If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then by Young's convolution inequality we have the estimate:
$$ \|f*g\|_{L^p}\leq \|f\|_{L^1}\|g\|_{L^p}.$$

Question: Let $\mu$ be a probability measure $\mu\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then the convolution  $g*\mu$ is defined as 
$$(g*\mu)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(x-y)\mu(dy).$$ 
Is there any hope of getting an estimate of Young's type in this case? What I would like to have is an estimate of the type 
$$\|g*\mu\|_{L^p}\leq A_\mu \|g\|_{L^p}, \text{ where $A$ is a quantity dependent on $\mu$ which stays bounded.} $$

Remarks:

(1) Note that if $\mu$ is an absolutely continuous measure w.r.t. the lebesgue measure i.e. $\mu<<\mathcal{L}_{{R}^n}$ then the Young's inequality holds.

(2) If $\mu$ is a dirac measure (in the sense of Lebesgue decomposition theorem) say $\mu=\delta_0$, a similar estimate follows as well
$$ \|g*\delta_0\|_{L^p}^p=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}dx\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(x-y)d\delta_0(dy)\right|=\|g\|_{L^p}.$$

By Lebesgue's decomposition theorem $\mu$ can be written as a sum of absolutely continuous part, discrete (delta) part and a cantor part. I do not know how to handle the Cantor part.

Possible Way (not too sure about this one): Since the estimate works for absolutely continuous measures (or $L^1$ densities) can we somehow arrive at a bound by some approximations?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it using approximations.  First suppose that $g \in C_c(\mathbb R^n)$.  Construct a sequence of measures $\mu_k$ that are absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure (or alternatively are finite linear combinations of dirac delta functions) such that $\mu_k$ converges weakly to $\mu$.  Then for each $x \in \mathbb R^n$, we have $\mu_k*g(x) \to \mu*g(x)$.  Now use the dominated convergence theorem to show that $\|\mu_k*g - \mu*g\|_p \to 0$, and go from there.

Comment: That indeed would work. However is it always possible to construct a weakly approximating sequence $\mu_n$ for a probability measure $\mu$?

Comment: For each $k$, divide $\mathbb R^n$ into small hypercubes whose sides are of length $2^{-k}$.  Define $f_k(x) = \mu(B)/|B|$, where $B$ is the cube containing $x$, and $|\cdot|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.  Then $f_k \, dx \to \mu$ weakly.